# Replacement of Google Adsense ad with Admob Ad

Tags: android, admob, adsense

actually, I made an app from a site. That is, I have shown data on my app which is fetched from the website using web view. But problem is that space is shown in place of ads which is embedded with the site. One solution is that if that ad is replaced by Admob or second solution is that if we block that ads in our app. Please suggest me and how could be it possible?

Comment: does the ads not show when you run the app on your device ?

Comment: no...the ads are not shown in my app

Comment: ok, did you develop the website? i will suggest to probably hide the adsense code in it and add the admob inside the android app

Comment: exactly i want to do this.. will you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: well you could follow the android docs for admob. have you tried looking them over yet ?

Comment: yaa.. but i could nt remove the space caused by ADsense ads of google..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135579/discussion-between-shubhank-and-megha-jain).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot replace ads inside webView (from website) with Admob.
Admob is for showing Ads inside Apps.
If you can change website layout to fit Mobile view and resize ads or use Responsive AdType from AdSense.

also if you want to advertise you apps or website through another app of yours you can use admob campaigns

Comment: how could be it possible ?

Comment: @MeghaJain What? to use responsive ad type or design mobile friendly website?

Comment: Cant I do anything in app to remove that space?

Comment: @MeghaJain from android app you cannot remove ads of website! unless the webpage be single and you can add view on android on top of ad position! but its ugly!

Comment: My site is also mobile responsive and ads also

Answer (score 0):

Megha notice that displaying adsense (admob) for mobile web inside apps is a violation of google policies [Ref](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/oLHJNwuB0vg)

Doing so may result in your account getting banned so avoid it as much as you can

Other then that you should not show ads inside webview since its not designed and optimized for apps and will result in very low conversions.

As i see it you need on your site detect if the user source is mobile and if so remove the ads. on your app side implement admob interstitial ads for maximum conversion and earnnings [Admob android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: ya i know.. but i want to remove that space instead. please help me out regarding this